# 10.8.5 kextunload failed, but works under all predecessors

Tags: usb, osx-mountain-lion, kernel-extension

I'm looking for some more detailed informaion about the latest 10.8.5 update related to kexts.

There is, so far, no IOUSBFamily Log Version available for 10.8.5, 
but don't know if this would help.

My kext (virtuall usb bus, derived from IOUSBControllerV3) works with all predecessors, 
but there must be a significant diff with 10.8.5 thats lets kextunload fail 
by typicall "class have 1 instance" error.

Thanks in advance for any hint,
regards
  Markus

---

Yes, I've overload the three

```
 virtual void taggedRetain(const void *tag)  const;
 virtual void taggedRelease(const void *tag) const;
 virtual void taggedRelease(const void * tag, const int freeWhen) const;
```

functions and see the outputs but get no idea who doesn't release his tag under 10.8.5?

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue significantly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353162/ioservice-leaking-for-no-reason