# IOService leaking for NO reason

Tags: c++, macos, memory-leaks, iokit, kernel-extension

Okay, I am completely stumped and frustrated. I was working on an I/O Kit RAM Disk implementation and discovered that it wasn't unloading when my friend loaded it with `kextload` and then tried to unload it with `kextunload`. The reason for this was that none of the `OSObject`s which the kext allocated were being freed. However, on both my computer (running Mac OS 10.8.5) and a VM (running Mac OS 10.7) everything worked as expected.

Eventually, I narrowed the problem down so much that I created a new Xcode project with a blank I/O Kit driver and tested it on my friend's machine. Lo and behold, I was unable to unload the module with `kextunload` because it was claiming that my `IOService` subclass was leaking. I would like to test another driver on my friend's machine where I don't override any `IOService` methods (in the version I tested, I override a few to do `IOLog`s before passing the call to `super`). I will update this with any extra information I collect about his machine's configuration.

Here is my header (BrokenDriver.h):

```
#include <IOKit/IOService.h>
#include <IOKit/IOLib.h>

class BrokenDriver : IOService {
    OSDeclareDefaultStructors(BrokenDriver)
public:
    virtual bool init(OSDictionary * dictionary = NULL);
    virtual void free();

    virtual bool start(IOService * provider);
    virtual void stop(IOService * provider);
};
```

And here is my implementation (BrokenDriver.cpp):

```
#define super IOService
OSDefineMetaClassAndStructors(BrokenDriver, IOService);

bool BrokenDriver::start(IOService * provider) {
    bool success;
    IOLog("%s[%p]::%s(%p)\n", getName(), this, __FUNCTION__, provider);
    success = super::start(provider);
    if (success) {
        // Don't worry, the problem persists even if I don't call registerService()
        registerService();
    }
    return success;
}

void BrokenDriver::stop(IOService * provider) {
    IOLog("%s[%p]::%s(%p)\n", getName(), this, __FUNCTION__, provider);    
    super::stop(provider);
}

bool BrokenDriver::init(OSDictionary * dictionary) {
    if (!super::init(dictionary)) {
        return false;
    }    
    IOLog("%s[%p]::%s(%p)\n", getName(), this, __FUNCTION__, dictionary);
    return true;
}

void BrokenDriver::free(void) {
    IOLog("%s[%p]::%s()\n", getName(), this, __FUNCTION__);
    super::free();
}
```

Additionally, since I know this could be the source of problems, here is the XML of my BrokenDriver-Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.aqnichol.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2013 Alex Nichol. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>BrokenDriver</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.aqnichol.BrokenDriver</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>BrokenDriver</string>
            <key>IOKitDebug</key>
            <integer>65535</integer>
            <key>IOMatchCategory</key>
            <string>BrokenDriver</string>
            <key>IOProbeScore</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOResources</string>
            <key>IOResourceMatch</key>
            <string>IOKit</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>9.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>9.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
        <string>9.0.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So, what's the verdict? Is my friend's kernel fried, or is it my brain? Is it even remotely possible that some other driver on his machine is attempting to persist my kext?

**UPDATE**: I tried again with an EMPTY implementation. That's right, I overrode exactly 0 methods of my own. The problem persists. Here is the message from `kextunload`:

```
(kernel) Can't unload kext com.aqnichol.BrokenDriver; classes have instances:
(kernel) Kext com.aqnichol.BrokenDriver class BrokenDriver has 1 instance.
Failed to unload com.aqnichol.BrokenDriver - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is the problem, but I notice that `IOService` is a **private** base of your class. I could imagine that this might trigger some subtle issues in Apple's runtime type info macros?

Try:

```
class BrokenDriver : public IOService
```